# Allow single code block to be used in multiple snippets in single post

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I searched through all (presently four or five) pages of stack-snippet questions, so if this has already been asked, I apologize.

That out of the way, I'm wondering if we might get the ability to... well, transclude separate sections of code into multiple snippets, but only in the context of a single post, be it question or answer.

That is to say, sometimes I've [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26825702/785241) that posts (including one of my own, that I won't be linking) make use of the same CSS/JavaScript/HTML sections, for multiple examples.

This leads to a cluttered question if the JavaScript `hide` function isn't utilized, and of course, repeating one's self.

I don't know what would have to be done to implement this, since I have little experience in the matter, but I think it would be useful to have the ability to write one block of HTML/CSS, and then reference that block in multiple examples... again, limited to the context of a single post. I mainly feel the limit of context is to prevent dependencies on other's code.

Comment: Is this really a frequent problem? And once implemented, will users know to use this feature? May be it's just me, or the fact that I don't follow the same tags you do, but I don't see much benefit in using such a feature in the first place.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I'm honestly not sure that it is, though I asked here to find out of it was a good idea, enough to warrant a change to the system.  So far, it doesn't appear to be the case that it is.

Comment: @jotik Please refrain from modifying several-year-old questions to just improve the grammar; they don't really need to be bumped to the front page because someone forgot to add two spaces after an I.

Comment: @Daedalus If you think your unanswered question doesn't need any more attention, why not delete it instead?

Comment: Stack Snippets (and code in questions in general) should be **minimal**, complete and verifiable examples. If there's enough code that copying it is such a hardship, there's probably too much code.

Comment: @jotik In case anyone feels like responding with an answer, however I do not believe it warrants being bumped to the front page for grammar edits.

Comment: @Daedalus It did earn me an excavator badge thou... :-D

Comment: @jotik That may be, but its better to use effort on questions that deserve it.